# Asserting a value error with property based testing

Tags: python, pytest, property-based-testing, python-hypothesis

I have a function which returns the divisors of a number `num`. The function raises an error if number is `negative`.
 I am using the hypothesis library to test this function but I am not sure how I can make it a property-based test.

This is my test:

```
@given(strategies.integers())
def test_valid(num):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        divisors(-3)
```

This code works but how can I change it so that the argument is "num" instead of being hardcoded. Similarly how can I assert that one is an element of the set, for any number num.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `divisors(-3)` to `divisors(num)`

```py
@given(strategies.integers())
def test_valid(num):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        divisors(num)
```

Bear in mind that `strategies.integers()` returns positive and negative numbers so you need to pass `max_value=0` to it to generate only negative.

In order to assert that `divisors` func returns `set` assign a returned value to variable and use [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance). The assert line could look like `assert isinstance(divisors(num), set)`.

Answer (score 0):

No comments credits yet, so providing this as an answer.

To return negative numbers `max_value=-1` should be used, as max_value is an inclusive boundary, i.e. if set to 0, 0 would be sampled.